# How to connect to web socket with APP_ID, APP_KEY and APP_SECRET with Flutter Application

Tags: flutter, dart, websocket

How to connect to web socket with APP_ID, APP_KEY, and APP_SECRET with Flutter Application.

Comment: To where? In what format? To what end? You are going to need to be a bit more specific. Also, have you tried it yourself? Have you looked on pub for packages related to websockets and followed their documentation?

Answer (score 0):

I used flutter_pusher_client and laravel_echo but I got `java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found error.

My Code

```
PusherOptions pusherOptions = PusherOptions(
  encrypted: true,
  host: 'socket.abcd.com',
  cluster: 'mt1',
  port: 6001,
);

FlutterPusher flutterPusher = FlutterPusher(
  'PUSHER_APP_KEY',
  pusherOptions,
  enableLogging: true,
);

Echo echo = Echo({
  'broadcaster': 'pusher',
  'client': flutterPusher,
  'wssHost': 'socket.abcd.com',
  'wssPort': 6001,
  'disableStats': true,
  'forceTLS': true,
  'autoConnect': true,
  'enabledTransports': ['ws', 'wss'],
});

flutterPusher.connect(
  onConnectionStateChange:
      (FPC.ConnectionStateChange connectionStateChange) {
    print(
      'PUSHER CONNECTION STATE CHANGE C: ${connectionStateChange.previousState} -> ${connectionStateChange.currentState}',
    );
  },
  onError: (FPC.ConnectionError connectionError) {
    print(
        'PUSHER CONNECTION ERROR C: ${connectionError.code} ${connectionError.exception} ${connectionError.message}');
  },
);

echo.join('chat')
  ..here((user) => print('ECHO USER: user'))
  ..listen('NewMessage', (event) {
    print('ECHO MESSAGE: $event');
  });
```